# Semantics of 'x = y = z' assignment in Python

Tags: python

I had the following line in a loop occurring during the initialization of a singly linked list class:

```
previous = previous.pointer = Node(item, None)
```

The intended semantics was what I can obtain with:

```
previous.pointer = Node(item, None)
previous = previous.pointer
```

What I found out using pdb is that `previous` gets reassigned to the new `Node` object. And the (former) `previous`'s pointer attribute is unchanged.

I couldn't find documentation about the expected behaviour of this kind of assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is well explained in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

> An assignment statement evaluates the expression list (remember that this can be a single expression or a comma-separated list, the latter yielding a tuple) and **assigns** the single resulting object **to each** of the target lists, **from left to right**.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Where the term `target_list` is used in the grammar as follows:

```
assignment_stmt ::=  (target_list "=")+ (expression_list | yield_expression)
```

<sup>(Note the `+` sign after the first parenthesis - this allows chain assignments)</sup>

Thus, the resulting semantics:

```
target_list1 = target_list2 = expression
```

is equivalent to:

```
target_list1 = expression
target_list2 = expression
```

There is no way of confusing what is being assigned (*evaluates the expression list*) with what is the target of the assignment, because assignment is a *statement*, not an *expression*. Hence, all with `=` in it, will not be treated as an expression - only the right most part. Next, all assignment statements will be processed left to right (i.e. their target lists will have the expression's value assigned).

Answer (score 2):

It should assign both, `previous.pointer` and `previous` to the newly created `Node`, effectively at the same time<sup>1</sup>.

<sup><sup>1</sup>I'm not sure which one gets assigned first (or if that's even defined by the specification -- though it should only matter in the case of *descriptors* like the builtin `property`).</sup>